# OpenGL compiling issues

Tags: c++, opengl, compiler-construction

I am using Visual Studio C++ and GLEW. The Project Settings are all set (Includes/Libs).

```
MenuState.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewUseProgramObjectARB
MenuState.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewLinkProgramARB
MenuState.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewAttachObjectARB
MenuState.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewCompileShader
MenuState.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewShaderSource
MenuState.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewCreateShader
MenuState.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewCreateProgramObjectARB
```

These are the only Messages I get. Everything worked fine until I tried to implement a Shader.
The Problem is I am working within a VM, so my question is: Does GLEW need opengl32.lib as a dependency? Because if I dont add the opengl32.lib to the Linker I get even more errors. And if so could the Problem be caused by the opengl32.lib? Because I think the opengl32.lib is the standard windows opengl32.lib, that would mean it's only opengl 1.1, and therefor it can't link...

So what is the issue about these errors?

Comment: You need to link with the glew library. Are you doing that?

Comment: @icktoofay What is `glue32.lib`?

Comment: @Christian: Sorry, I mistyped. I was thinking of how I'd pronounce `glew` and I accidentally typed it.

Comment: sure glew32.lib and I also added the other libs that were in the lib directory to be sure... so glew32mx.lib; glew32mxs.lib; glew32s.lib aswell at the moment I just wanted to make sure that it's not the problem. opengl32.lib is added aswell

Comment: @user986803 You shouldn't link to both the static and dynamic libraries of GLEW, so just drop the `...s.lib` versions.

Comment: I did, still doesnt change a thing... Can't it be the opengl32.lib of the 7.0 win sdk?

Comment: For GLEW to work you should link against `glew32.lib`, `glu32.lib`, and `opengl32.lib` as stated in the [installation instructions](http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html). Apart from that: what version of Visual Studio are you on? Maybe the .lib files you are using were generated with another version, rendering them unusable with your version. Building GLEW yourself should fix that.

Comment: You might try [GLee](http://elf-stone.com/glee.php) instead, which is MUCH easier to use.  Just download a .c and .h file from svn and add them to your project.

Comment: I am on Visual Studio 2010, the lib and includes I put in the win sdk, the dll is in windows/system32... There must be some problem because I just wanted to get the opengl version, but I get another error

    glewInit();
    if (glewIsSupported("GL_VERSION_2_0"))
    throw Exception("Ready for OpenGL 2.0\n");
    else 
    throw Exception("OpenGL 2.0 not supported\n");

    Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glewIsSupported referenced in function _WinMain@16
    Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glewInit referenced in function _WinMain@16

Comment: @user986803: That happens if you try to statically link GLEW. You've to add a #define GLEW_BUILD GLEW_STATIC before including the glew.h

Comment: I use not my own compiled version of glew right now, and then the errors are not coming up anymore... so it was probably something wrong with my glew version... however I now get runtime errors... unhandled exception: glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport)... If I comment that out the next get function complains... Any Ideas? Btw I commented out the Shader part right now, so I am just trying to get everything working that was working with the gl.h and glu.h ....

Comment: @all:I got everything workin! I am really sorry to have bothered you all... The last bit of the problem was that I had an opengl32.dll in the debug output directory... that was not working for my VM (the dll was a leftover from the university pcs...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to #define GLEW_STATIC in the project before including GLEW in Windows. Then you can just include the entire source code in your project files. Otherwise, you need to have the proper GLEW DLL file in with your executable.